# Testing Android Apps on a 4.0.3 device with 2.2 and 4.1 sdks installed

Tags: android, eclipse

So I've been playing around with the Virtual Devices for a while working on a few Android Apps. I have the 2.2 and 4.1 SDKs installed on the computer like is suggested by the developers website (this incorporates most of the phones around today).

Recently I purchased an Android phone, the HTC One XL running Android 4.0.3, and in trying to run my apps through it, the system is not finding the device.

I fiddled around a bit searching for the device but it says that it is searching for 4.1 devices in the Android Device chooser.

The phone is in debugging mode, and as far as I can tell, the most up to date driver is installed.

So, is there a way to tell Eclipse to look for devices with lower OS's or should I uninstall the 4.1 kit and put on the 4.0.3? Or is there a better option?

Comment: Is adb not finding the device or is Eclipse not giving you the choice of device when you try to run your app.

Comment: try to run adb devices. If your devixce is not listed, then reinstall your drivers. On an ICS device you can run all apps with API Level 15<